# Why doesn't DRF enforce non-empty field?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

I am using a custom user model:

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models

class User(AbstractUser):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=120, 
                unique=True, 
                blank=False,
                validators=[MinLengthValidator(6)])
    email = models.EmailField('Email Address', unique=True, blank=False)
    FCM_ID = models.CharField(max_length=300)
```

I was hoping that I won't be allowed to create a user with blank email field, but for some reason, I can do so without any errors.

> `User().save()`  successfully adds a user with all blank fields. The `unique` condition, however, is enforced as expected. Why is `blank=False` not enforced?

Here's the custom user manager:

```py
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import BaseUserManager

class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, **kwargs):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("The email must be set")
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **kwargs)
        user.save()
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **kwargs):
        ...
```

Edit: I made the email field `blank=False` as well; but to no avail.

Comment: In given code `blank=false` is applied to `username` only, not `email`.

Comment: @IvanStarostin In any case, wouldn't blank username be invalid in this case? And yet I can create a `User` with an empty string.

Comment: Still, no DRF code shown so not clear if you use forms or drf. Consider defining `required` attribute in DRF serializer https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#required Also please check for possible migrations needed (`makemigrations`, `migrate`)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, `blank=False` is not enforced on the database level, it is only checked when you're validating model in your code, which is not happening by itself when calling `save()` on it. You need to invoke `clean_fields` at least before saving the model.

Read about validating models in [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects).

If you are using Django models through DRF serializers or Django forms, they may do some validation as well, so refer to their documentation to find out how it will be handled.